# Trivial omission: This user not earned any badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I just stumbled upon a user profile where the badge count was zero. The accompanying message is missing a "has":

[image: This user not earned any badges]

Comment: Stackoverflow no give George badges.  Make George angry. George go club unicorn.

Comment: Speaking of trivial omissions; "Y U no use hand-drawn circles?"

Comment: -1 For discriminating Yoda, the secret developer at SE, -1 for not using hand drawn cycles, -1 for not having any badges.

Comment: Give this user badge. Problem solved.

Comment: I had to read this like 3 times before I saw what the problem was. The mind is a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed when rev 2013.8.9.1321 (meta) / 2013.8.9.926 (sites) rolls out.