# Another "badges" bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Zero-badge users [get no love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192511/136323) on StackOverflow...

I just found that the status text for users with no badges, seen from the <kbd>activity</kbd> tab, features a text that refers to *answers*, not badges.

[image: no answers?]

(Now with *red* hand-drawn circles!)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Circle is now red.

Comment: Well, this is just part of a larger bug that is endemic to Stack Overflow; if you have less than 15,000 EXP, you don't matter on this network. You may as well just take this bug request, and tweet to @codinghorror so he can laugh at you while from his yacht's bridge.

Comment: I cannot believe that a suggested edit to make the circle red was accepted.

Comment: status-accepted

Comment: @jeffreylin_ [Freehand circles are important, you know.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/223030)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in rev 2013.8.9.1321 (meta) / 2013.8.9.926 (sites).